# Is it possible to buy Ethereum without any service fee using Debit/credit card?

Tags: coinbase

I just installed the Coinbase app and when I select the add payment method it says 2.5% of service fee of visa and master card.

Is there any app where I can buy crypto-currencies without paying any fees to the middleman and buy directly?

Comment: LocalEthereum will probably be your best bet

Comment: Not forgetting you will still pay a fee, it just won't be upfront and quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best resource would be [bittybot](http://bittybot.co/uk/).
They'll give you the price comparison between different exchanges in the U.K.
Coinbase and debit card works ok for me. Check local bitcoins too for price comparison. Bittylicous can also be good at certain times too.